# System Call to check pte_present()

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls

I am working on an OS assignment to check if a virtual address of a process is stored in memory or on the disk. I think I had it working, but, part of the assignment was to use a lock with this code:

```
spinlock_t *lock;
ptep = pte_offset_map_lock(mm, pmd, address, &lock);
...
pte_unmap_unlock(ptep, lock)
```

I get several errors when I `make -j4` that I don't quite understand. I have scoured the internet, but, it seems that these errors lead people to use `pte_offset_kernel()`, which isn't really an option for me. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#include <asm/pgtable.h>

asmlinkage int sys_memordisk_3_2(unsigned long v_add, int pid)
{
    struct task_struct *p_task = find_task_by_vpid(pid);
    struct mm_struct *p_mm;
    p_mm = p_task->mm;
    spinlock_t *lock;

    int data = 0;
    pgd_t *pgd;
    pud_t *pud;
    pmd_t *pmd;
    pte_t *ptep, pte;
    pgd = pgd_offset(p_mm, v_add);
    pud = pud_offset(pgd, v_add);
    pmd = pmd_offset(pud, v_add);

    ptep = pte_offset_map_lock(p_mm, pmd, v_add, &lock);
    pte = *ptep;
    data = pte_present(pte);

    printk(KERN_EMERG "Present flag: %i\n", data?1:0);

    pte_unmap_unlock(ptep, lock);

    return 0;
}
```

And I get these errors when I try to make the kernel with this system call:

```
sys_memordisk_3_2.c: In function ‘sys_memordisk_3_2’:
sys_memordisk_3_2.c:49: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
sys_memordisk_3_2.c:65: error: implicit declaration of function ‘in_nmi’
sys_memordisk_3_2.c:65: error: implicit declaration of function ‘in_irq’
sys_memordisk_3_2.c:76: error: implicit declaration of function ‘kunmap_atomic’
```

I can not find information on the in_nmi, in_irq, and/or kunmap_atomic errors that allow me to use the provided function. I'm hoping someone can explain what I've done wrong here, or point me to a source that I can try to decipher. Thank you!

Comment: `I can not find information on the in_nmi, in_irq, and/or kunmap_atomic errors that allow me to use the provided function.` - There are even sites, which allows to find function's definition online. [Example for in_nmi](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.9.11/ident/in_nmi): as you can see, you need to `#include <linux/hardirq.h>` for use given macro.

Comment: right, but, I'm not using these functions in my code, which is why I included the full code.

Comment: I went ahead and added that and `#include <linux/highmem.h>` and the code compiles. I still get the ISO error and I don't understand why these functions are popping up if I didn't call them. However, it compiled, so I will see if it is working.

Comment: `ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code` means that you should declare all local variables before any other code. But you have a *code* `p_mm = p_task->mm;` followed by a *declaration* `spinlock_t *lock;`. `I'm not using these functions in my code` - probably, you use them via macros. BTW, the error message contains the line number, so you may check that (I cannot check that, because your code doesn't contain line numbers for matching errors).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I got so confused I forgot about the line numbers. Everything is working perfectly now - I don't know how to choose your answer as the right solution because this was all in comments. But I genuinely appreciate the help!